# Changes made to /etc/extlinux/extlinux.conf are not loaded after reboot

Tags: boot-loader

I have some trouble with usb autosuspend and found that with extlinux you can change the config file to disable it.
So I added `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` to the APPEND line

```
 APPEND ${cbootargs} usbcore.autosuspend=-1
```

However when I cat `/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend` after a reboot it still reports 2.

How can I apply the changes or is there something I am doing wrong

The device is a Nvidia Jetson Xavier

Answer (score 0):

If `usbcore` is loaded as a kernel module (see `lsmod | grep ^usbcore`), then you might instead add a `.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d/` directory, e.g. `/etc/modprobe.d/usboptions.conf`, with the following contents:

```
options usbcore autosuspend=-1
```

If the system uses initramfs, the usbcore may be loaded before the real root filesystem is mounted and the system is still running form initramfs, and so you'll need to update/regenerate your initramfs file. Since the Jetson Xavier's OS image seems to be derived from Ubuntu, try `sudo update-initramfs -u` for regenerating your initramfs file.

Comment: I tried this and but `/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend` still reports a 2. I can sort of solve it by setting it to -1 via `/etc/rc.local` since the power to the usb hubs I use are turned on later so the edited autosuspend value will be used. But I rather have it working via the official way